# How can I properly share the Amplify framework with my Main App and my App Extension for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, aws-amplify, swift-package-manager

I have an iOS app using AWS amplify for the backend.  I am using Xcode 13 and SwiftUI.
I previously added the Amplify framework using Cocoapods however I was unable to get the framework to work with the extension.

So I recently switched to Swift Package Manager.  I added the package to my main project.  Then I went to my Share Extension and in General - Frameworks and Libraries and manually added the libraries.

After doing this the app builds and runs and both the main app and extension work fine and are able to use the libraries.

The problem is that I cannot archive and upload the app to the App Store.  I get the following error:

> CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the
> CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.amazonaws.AWSAuthCore' under the iOS
> application 'MyAPP.app'. With error code
> STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR...

I went on many forums and spent many hours trying to fix this but to no avail.  The suggestions are to click 'do not embed' for the libraries but that option is not available for me.

I wonder if there is anyway to resolve this?

Below are my General and Build Phases for the Share Extension:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just remove explicit `Amplify` dependency from extension, ie. next section should be empty

[image: demo1]

Make sure (it should be automatically, but anyway)

1. *Link Frameworks Automatically* parameter (in Build Settings) is `true`

[image: demo2]

2. *Runpath Search Path* parameter is related to main bundle

[image: demo3]

So as targets from SPM are built in same location as product and extension and automatic framework linking is enabled the imported modules in extension will available and linked automatically and due to run paths are set the frameworks will be found in run-time as well.

*Note: of course in main app target all should be included*

[image: demo4]

Tested with Xcode 13.1 / iOS 15.1

Comment: I have removed the explicitly added modules from the Extension and confirmed that the default settings in 1. and 2. above are as you have shown.  Restarted, cleaned and built and get error in extension that 'No such module 'Amplify'.  So despite being linked for some reason it is not recognizing the amplify libraries.  Is there anything else I should be checking?  I previously had the libraries added by cocoa pods and then removed cocoapods using pod deintegrate before using SPM.  Now I am not opening .xcworkspace but just opening .xcodeproj file.

Comment: Yes, right after clean Xcode tells "cannot find module", but after one (or two) tries it compiles ok. I assume it is Xcode caching defect (as observed since Xcode 12, or 11, in memory caching works bad).

Comment: I tried many times but still not working.  I tried deleting and reinstalling Xcode, clearing derived data.  nothing woks.  I created a new project and did as you suggest.  the first time I try to add amplify  it recognizes the module in the extension and builds.  but opening my other app then coming back to this app and the same behavior.  The module that previously built is no longer building with same error in extension 'No such module 'Amplify'.  I am completely at a loss here.

Comment: It sounds as something is wrong with configuration of your real project... well, try to set FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS explicitly.

Comment: sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: I have just tried creating another new project and the result is so inconsistent.  This time in the new project when I build it says 'cannot find module' in the share extension file when I try to import amplify.  Can you confirm it is consistently working for you?